# mod_rewrite and slash problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to redirect url`s like this

http://example/foo/bar/

http://example/foo/bar

to

http://example/foo/bar.php

Here is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It works with http://example/foo/bar but if the url is ending with slash a error rise (Internal Server Error)
What to to do so both url types to work properly ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the / got matched in the group .*, so you call http://example/foo/bar/.php

To make both works use :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
```

**EDIT:** forget when we ask a file in the first place

Comment: Thanks but it still give me Internal Server Error if the url is like http://example.com/foo/bar/

Comment: Yes, cause I matched the files as well. RewriteCond shall avoid that. All .php files call does not get rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is really what you want to do, then:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/?$  $1.php
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it works.